# Compile a dylib (dll/so) and output it in a specific path

Tags: rust, dll, rust-cargo

My Rust app comprises the main program and some DLLs (also in Rust). They must be placed in the "plugins" subfolder.

**How can Cargo automatically output the compiled file (in my case, each DLL) into a specific path?**

using `cargo build --workspace` compiles all at once, but they are all placed in the same folder (`target/debug`) and I have to manually reorganize them every single time.

Comment: Write a short script that will copy them.

Comment: Instead of copying/moving them you could create a symlink in the target location `ln -s target/debug/libyourlib.so plugins/libyourlib.so` on linux or other unix like.

Comment: the problem with the scripting of symlinking is that it's a very Unix solution. But anyway, how could I invoke such a script automatically during cargo build/run?